# How to retrieve converted image in Spatie laravel-medialibrary?

Tags: laravel

I'm uploading images using the spatie media library and the images get uploaded and converted successfully. When accessing an uploaded image as below it works:

```
 @foreach ($articles as $article)
     <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>
     <img src="{{ $article->getFirstMediaUrl() }}" alt="">
 @endforeach
```

How can I access the converted images? I think I'm missing something from the documentation to make it work.

My model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;



class Article extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia;

    protected $fillable = ['title'];

    public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
            ->width(250)
            ->height(90);
    }
}
```

My store function

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $article = Article::create(['title' => 'First title']);
        $article->addMedia($file)->toMediaCollection();
        return back();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use getUrl() method to access the media url, so change your template like this.

`<img src="{{ $article->getFirstMediaUrl()->getUrl() }}" alt="">`

you will get the converted file perhaps if you want to access other object you can use other library function though from the document
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction

Comment: That throws an error  ```Call to a member function getUrl() on string```

Comment: This works ```<img src="{{ $article->getFirstMedia()->getUrl('thumb') }}" alt="">```

Comment: if you want to access absolute path of the Media file then you can also use `getPath()`  method

Comment: Okay, noted with thanks!